# Split a string on several separators while keeping one or more separator

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to split a string based on several separators while keeping some of the separators in the splitted array?
So if I have the string `"This is a-weird string,right?"` I would like to get

`["This", "is", "a", "-", "weird", "string", ",", "right", "?"]`

I have tried using `string.split(/([^a-zA-Z])/g)`, but I don't want to keep the whitespace. [This guide](https://stackabuse.com/regex-splitting-by-character-unless-in-quotes/) seems like being something I can use, but my understanding of regex is not good enough to know how to mix those two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```js
console.log("This is a-weird string,right?".match(/[^\W_]+|[^\w\s]|_/g))
```

The regex matches:

- `[^\W_]+` - one or more alphanumeric chars
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\s]` - any char other than word and whitespace
- `|` - or
- `_` - an underscore.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OugEEb/1).

**A fully Unicode aware regex** will be

```js
console.log("This is ą-węird string,right？".match(/[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}]+|[\p{P}\p{S}]/gu))
```

Here,

- `[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}]+` - one or more Unicode letters, diacritics or digits
- `|` - or
- `[\p{P}\p{S}]` - a single punctuation proper or symbol char.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OugEEb/3).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex splitting approach.  We can try splitting on the following pattern:

```
\s+|(?<=\w)(?=\W)|(?<=\W)(?=\w)
```

Code snippet:

```js
var input = "This is a-weird string,right?";
var parts = input.split(/\s+|(?<=\w)(?=\W)|(?<=\W)(?=\w)/);
console.log(parts);
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used, which says to split on:

```
\s+            whitespace
|              OR
(?<=\w)(?=\W)  the boundary between a word character preceding and non word
               character following
|              OR
(?<=\W)(?=\w)  the boundary between a non word character preceding and word
               character following
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```js
const str = "This is a-weird string,right?";

var arr = str.replace(/(\S)([\,\-])/g, "$1 $2").replace(/([\,\-])(\S)/g, "$1 $2").split(" ");

console.log(arr);
```

You can replace using each delimiter you're interested in so that it has a space on each side, then use that to split and return an array.

Comment: This solves the case, but if there is a space after the `,` or `-`, an empty string is created in the array `[... "string", ",", "''", "right?"]` if the string was `"... string, right?"`.

Comment: That's true! Although I've made a correction to that and this option might be slightly easier to understand with less regex experience, in hindsight, an all regex solution is simply more efficient. I think you chose the best answer :)